# Django1.10: how to create 2 objects with foreign key relationship in one transaction

Tags: django

I have 2 models:

```
class Vendor(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...
class User(models.Model):
    ...
```

I want to create the user and vendor in one transaction:

```
    with transaction.atomic():
        user = User(name="test")
        user.save()
        vendor = Vendor(admin=user)
        vendor.save()
```

But I get error :
ValueError: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'admin'.
How to fix this error? How to create these 2 objects in 1 transaction?

Comment: That code shouldn't give the error, since you called `user.save()` before 
`vendor = Vendor(admin=user)`. Please show the actual code and full traceback.

Comment: Yes @Alasdair is right. Were do you use that transaction?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my problem: The primary key of model User was not defined as AutoField, so after save, the User object is not a complete object: the primary key is missing. I think that cause the error. After I set the primary key to AutoField, the error is resolved.